# How to report tab ready progress percentage in Mozilla Addon SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to be able to monitor the loading percentage of a loaded tab in Mozilla Addon SDK.

Simple example code:

```
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
let percentage = 0;
tabs.on('ready', function(){
  percentage = 100;
});

// what else can we listen to to determined the progress?

tabs.open({
  url: 'http://mozilla.org'
});
```

Is there any SDK API's that emit the progress percentage of the tab or is it a case of monitoring the events and guessing if the tab is at X%